# wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated() waiting for Json attribute

Tags: jmeter

I am using below wait statement to wait for xpath to display in UI.
wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath("(.//div[@class='rowr'])")))

I would like to apply the same statement but I need to wait for an attribute from response to display.
EX:
wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(id) //ID from json payload
Is there a way I can do that?

My JSON payload:
{
"exists": true,
"id": "ID0003930"
}

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait until `ID0003930` will be present in the HTML page in the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) you could go for something like:

```
var wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 10)

waitForId = function() {
    return WDS.browser.executeScript("return document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf('ID000393')") != -1
}

wait.until(new com.google.common.base.Function(waitForId))
```

More information:

- [Using Java from Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: Thanks, Dimitri.I have used your way and i am able to wait for ID